# SpecFlow - Integration testing (messaging architecture + scheduling issues)

Tags: .net, testing, messaging, specflow

We are currently using SpecFlow to do some integration testing. This is somewhat challenging when using a messaging architecture and time based tests.

For the messaging architecture we currently do the flowing:
1) API call is made.
2) SpecFlow checks the queues every x time until it's empty before proceeding.
3) Empty queues = processing is done so that means assertions are left.

For time based tests we currently don't have an good idea on how to implement this. For instance, we sometimes schedule a message in the future. When it comes back it produces a result. What we do now is make sure the scheduling time is limited to let's say one minute based on the input and then wait a minute before asserting. This works, but as more and more tests are written and SpecFlow needs to wait more and more, the tests become slower which I don't want.

How do others tackle these issues?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can avoid the issue around waiting for tests that take time taking time, other than running the tests in parallel. [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net), (warning, paid tool!) has a multi-threaded test runner which plays nicely with SpecFlow tests which may help, and it runs on the [build server](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/guides_console-tool-usage)

Comment: Can you wait a shorter amount of time, say 5 seconds? At the root of your test is "X should happen in the future", not "X should happen one minute from now."

Comment: @SamHolder I will take a look at NCrunch, running tests in parallel sounds like an option worth exploring.

Comment: @GregBurghardt we cannot wait shorter than one minute since the system is build with minute precision and unfortunately not second precision.

Comment: Could you schedule all the messages at once, then run all the tests? That way you would be waiting around one minute, and then the tests get run asserting that messages where sent.

Comment: @GregBurghardt sounds good, but I want to keep it as simple as possible for the test writer. He/she does not need to know about the other tests. So I see it as follows; one test executes, initializes the scheduling and then what? It finished successfully? Only for another test to continue the flow after the scheduler has fired? How will I be able to determine test priority in SpecFlow?

Answer (score 0):

I've been chewing on this question for a day now, and I *think* I may have come up with a hack job solution. First, isolate all the message tests in their own Feature. The first scenario just creates all the messages that will be published in the future, and then waits 1 minute. After that, each scenario makes assertions for one of the messages under test:

```
Feature: Publishing messages in the future
    ...

Scenario: Setting up the rest of the tests
    Given the message "foo" will be published 1 minute from now
    And the message "bar" will be published 1 minute from now
    And I wait 1 minute

Scenario: Foo got published
    Then the message "foo" should have been published

Scenario: Bar got published
    Then the message "bar" should have been published
```

This way you are waiting a little over one minute, and then making several assertions -- one in each scenario.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put in the example, but I still don't think this is it: 1) The tester needs to spread his scenario over two scenario's. 2) When more publishing features exist, you still have the problem that not all messages are scheduled first (only per feature) and you are still waiting in between features. With 10 features, that is 10 minutes.